# Failed to install llama-cpp-python with Metal on M2 Ultra

Tags: macos, metal, llama-cpp-python

I followed the instruction on https://llama-cpp-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/macos/.

My macOS version is Sonoma 14.4, and xcode-select is already installed (version: 15.3.0.0.1.1708646388).

I created a conda environment with 
"conda version : 24.1.2" 
"python version : 3.10.13.final.0" 
"platform : osx-arm64".

And I run the following command to install llama-cpp-python

```
CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL=on" pip install -U llama-cpp-python --no-cache-dir
```

, but it ends up with the following error message.

```
Collecting llama-cpp-python
  Downloading llama_cpp_python-0.2.57.tar.gz (36.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 36.9/36.9 MB 34.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.5.0 in /Users/mjchoi/miniforge3/envs/llama/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from llama-cpp-python) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.0 in /Users/mjchoi/miniforge3/envs/llama/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from llama-cpp-python) (1.26.1)
Collecting diskcache>=5.6.1 (from llama-cpp-python)
  Downloading diskcache-5.6.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.11.3 in /Users/mjchoi/miniforge3/envs/llama/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from llama-cpp-python) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /Users/mjchoi/miniforge3/envs/llama/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jinja2>=2.11.3->llama-cpp-python) (2.1.3)
Downloading diskcache-5.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 45.5/45.5 kB 405.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Building wheels for collected packages: llama-cpp-python
  Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [66 lines of output]
      *** scikit-build-core 0.8.2 using CMake 3.27.7 (wheel)
      *** Configuring CMake...
      2024-03-19 17:44:25,052 - scikit_build_core - WARNING - libdir/ldlibrary: /Users/mjchoi/miniforge3/envs/llama/lib/libpython3.10.a is not a real file!
      2024-03-19 17:44:25,052 - scikit_build_core - WARNING - Can't find a Python library, got libdir=/Users/mjchoi/miniforge3/envs/llama/lib, ldlibrary=libpython3.10.a, multiarch=darwin, masd=None
      loading initial cache file /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/CMakeInit.txt
      -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
      -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)")
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
      -- Found Threads: TRUE
      -- Accelerate framework found
      -- Metal framework found
      -- Warning: ccache not found - consider installing it for faster compilation or disable this warning with LLAMA_CCACHE=OFF
      -- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: arm64
      -- ARM detected
      -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_FP16_FORMAT_I3E
      -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_FP16_FORMAT_I3E - Failed
      CMake Warning (dev) at vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeLists.txt:1218 (install):
        Target llama has RESOURCE files but no RESOURCE DESTINATION.
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
      
      CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:21 (install):
        Target llama has PUBLIC_HEADER files but no PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION.
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
      
      CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:30 (install):
        Target llama has PUBLIC_HEADER files but no PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION.
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
      
      -- Configuring done (0.4s)
      -- Generating done (0.0s)
      -- Build files have been written to: /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build
      *** Building project with Ninja...
      Change Dir: '/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build'
      
      Run Build Command(s): /opt/homebrew/bin/ninja -v
      [1/25] cd /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/vendor/llama.cpp && xcrun -sdk macosx metal -O3 -c /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.metal -o /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.air && xcrun -sdk macosx metallib /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.air -o /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/default.metallib && rm -f /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.air && rm -f /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-common.h && rm -f /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.metal
      FAILED: bin/default.metallib /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/default.metallib
      cd /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/vendor/llama.cpp && xcrun -sdk macosx metal -O3 -c /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.metal -o /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.air && xcrun -sdk macosx metallib /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.air -o /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/default.metallib && rm -f /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.air && rm -f /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-common.h && rm -f /var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/tmp6kq2va35/build/bin/ggml-metal.metal
      xcrun: error: unable to find utility "metal", not a developer tool or in PATH
      [2/25] cd /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.27.7/bin/cmake -DMSVC= -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION=15.0.0.15000309 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID=AppleClang -DCMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME= -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -P /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/common/../scripts/gen-build-info-cpp.cmake
      -- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)")
      [3/25] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -DACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64 -DACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK -DGGML_SCHED_MAX_COPIES=4 -DGGML_USE_ACCELERATE -DGGML_USE_METAL -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/. -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu11 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fPIC -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wcast-qual -Wno-unused-function -Wunreachable-code-break -Wunreachable-code-return -Wdouble-promotion -MD -MT vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-alloc.c.o -MF vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-alloc.c.o.d -o vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-alloc.c.o -c /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/ggml-alloc.c
      [4/25] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -DACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64 -DACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK -DGGML_SCHED_MAX_COPIES=4 -DGGML_USE_ACCELERATE -DGGML_USE_METAL -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/. -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu11 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fPIC -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wcast-qual -Wno-unused-function -Wunreachable-code-break -Wunreachable-code-return -Wdouble-promotion -MD -MT vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-backend.c.o -MF vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-backend.c.o.d -o vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-backend.c.o -c /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/ggml-backend.c
      [5/25] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -DGGML_USE_METAL -DLLAMA_BUILD -DLLAMA_SHARED -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/. -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/../.. -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/../../common -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/. -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fPIC -Wno-cast-qual -MD -MT vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/CMakeFiles/llava.dir/llava.cpp.o -MF vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/CMakeFiles/llava.dir/llava.cpp.o.d -o vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/CMakeFiles/llava.dir/llava.cpp.o -c /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/llava.cpp
      [6/25] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -DACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64 -DACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK -DGGML_SCHED_MAX_COPIES=4 -DGGML_USE_ACCELERATE -DGGML_USE_METAL -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/. -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu11 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fPIC -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wcast-qual -Wno-unused-function -Wunreachable-code-break -Wunreachable-code-return -Wdouble-promotion -MD -MT vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-metal.m.o -MF vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-metal.m.o.d -o vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-metal.m.o -c /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/ggml-metal.m
      [7/25] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -DACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64 -DACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK -DGGML_SCHED_MAX_COPIES=4 -DGGML_USE_ACCELERATE -DGGML_USE_METAL -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/. -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu11 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fPIC -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wcast-qual -Wno-unused-function -Wunreachable-code-break -Wunreachable-code-return -Wdouble-promotion -MD -MT vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-quants.c.o -MF vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-quants.c.o.d -o vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml-quants.c.o -c /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/ggml-quants.c
      [8/25] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -DACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64 -DACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK -DGGML_SCHED_MAX_COPIES=4 -DGGML_USE_ACCELERATE -DGGML_USE_METAL -DLLAMA_BUILD -DLLAMA_SHARED -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -Dllama_EXPORTS -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/. -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fPIC -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wcast-qual -Wno-unused-function -Wunreachable-code-break -Wunreachable-code-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wextra-semi -MD -MT vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/llama.dir/unicode.cpp.o -MF vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/llama.dir/unicode.cpp.o.d -o vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/llama.dir/unicode.cpp.o -c /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/unicode.cpp
      [9/25] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -DGGML_USE_METAL -DLLAMA_BUILD -DLLAMA_SHARED -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/. -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/../.. -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/../../common -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/. -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fPIC -Wno-cast-qual -MD -MT vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/CMakeFiles/llava.dir/clip.cpp.o -MF vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/CMakeFiles/llava.dir/clip.cpp.o.d -o vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/CMakeFiles/llava.dir/clip.cpp.o -c /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/examples/llava/clip.cpp
      [10/25] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -DACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64 -DACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK -DGGML_SCHED_MAX_COPIES=4 -DGGML_USE_ACCELERATE -DGGML_USE_METAL -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/. -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu11 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fPIC -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wcast-qual -Wno-unused-function -Wunreachable-code-break -Wunreachable-code-return -Wdouble-promotion -MD -MT vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml.c.o -MF vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml.c.o.d -o vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/ggml.dir/ggml.c.o -c /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/ggml.c
      [11/25] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -DACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64 -DACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK -DGGML_SCHED_MAX_COPIES=4 -DGGML_USE_ACCELERATE -DGGML_USE_METAL -DLLAMA_BUILD -DLLAMA_SHARED -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -Dllama_EXPORTS -I/private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/. -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fPIC -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wcast-qual -Wno-unused-function -Wunreachable-code-break -Wunreachable-code-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wextra-semi -MD -MT vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/llama.dir/llama.cpp.o -MF vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/llama.dir/llama.cpp.o.d -o vendor/llama.cpp/CMakeFiles/llama.dir/llama.cpp.o -c /private/var/folders/kl/zn5jq0yn7fbb5rr67rmyfsrr0000gn/T/pip-install-u_i4wi0c/llama-cpp-python_6f999557aa7a4fc790f0ac043d8dc610/vendor/llama.cpp/llama.cpp
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
      
      
      *** CMake build failed
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llama-cpp-python
Failed to build llama-cpp-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried the following commands instead

```
export CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL=on" 
export FORCE_CMAKE=1 
pip install llama-cpp-python --no-cache-dir
```

, but I just got the same error message.

I also tried an older python version as in the link (3.9.16) but it did not work either.

Can someone please help me on this? Thanks much in advance.

Comment: `xcrun: error: unable to find utility "metal", not a developer tool or in PATH`. I think you need xcode installed and selected via xcode-select, I'm not sure if command line tools are enough to have `metal`

Comment: Many thanks! I missed that error message. I'll try to follow the solution found in https://github.com/gfx-rs/gfx/issues/2309. Hope that it works.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I'd like to thank Spo1ler's finding.

I only installed xcode-select not Xcode.app and its path was

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Based on https://github.com/gfx-rs/gfx/issues/2309#issuecomment-506130902,
I installed Xcode.app from Apple App Store.
Then, I can see that the path of xcode-select is changed automatically to

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Then, I had to run Xcode.app first to agree to the Xcode license agreements. After that, the following commands work.

```
export CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL=on" 
export FORCE_CMAKE=1 
pip install llama-cpp-python --no-cache-dir
```

But, I got another error message when I call LlamaCpp module as follows.

```
ggml_metal_init: default.metallib not found, loading from source
ggml_metal_init: GGML_METAL_PATH_RESOURCES = nil
ggml_metal_init: loading '/Users/.../miniforge3/envs/llama/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_cpp/ggml-metal.metal'    
ggml_metal_init: error: Error Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "program_source:3:10: fatal error: 'ggml-common.h' file not found
```

This is resolved after I uninstall llama-cpp-python by

```
pip uninstall llama-cpp-python -y
```

and install again with the following command with additional option

```
CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL_EMBED_LIBRARY=ON -DLLAMA_METAL=on" pip install llama-cpp-python --no-cache-dir
```

Then, I can confirm that LlamaCpp works well.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

1. Install Xcode.app from the appstore
2. sudo xcode-select -r